# redmine and mod_vhost_dbd

Tags: apache, redmine

I've problem to run redmine with vhost_dbd_module from apache. Redmine was installed under /var/www/redmine/ directory. My apache config look:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName HOSTNAME
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/" # THIS IS NOT WORKING
    # DocumentRoot "/var/www/redmine/public" # THIS WORKS WITH REDMINE
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    DBDriver mysql
    DBDParams host=localhost,user=test,pass=test,dbname=test
    DBDocRoot "SELECT document_root FROM vhosts WHERE server_name = %s"  HOSTNAME
</VirtualHost>
```

Field **document_root** from database return '/var/www/redmain/public' - so it should works. It works for php projects where index file is under '/var/www/project/public'. Besides the page return 404 because in /var/www/redmain/public there is no index file. I want universal config

Any suggestions?
Best regards, Peter

Answer (score 0):

Not havng a index.html is ok :) Check your `config/routes.rb`.
If rails service is running then your redmine rails check your routes.rb and deliver the default page there (view).

Comment: But what do you exactly suggest? I don't have dedicated 404 page error if I put wrong url, so I think there no rails are running. Server still serve files from **public** redmine directory.

Comment: /var/www/redmine/public is the correct directory in your case, but you get a 404 because probably no rails task running, start your rails server for your redmine installation, then all is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Passenger as an apache module is not compatible with about all modules used to define "dynamic" document roots (including `mod_vhost_dbd`). For passenger, you have to statically configure your apps in the Apache configuration.

Generally, you will have a hard time emulating your PHP setup with any Ruby app server, as they expect to be started once and run continuously, unlike PHP "apps" which act as scripts resolved and started new for each request. You should rethink your setup for persistent application server processes.

Comment: Can you recommend other configuration? I want to have multiple ruby/gem instances in my server (rvm). Each project can have different configurations (gemsets) and maybe passengers(?) in various versions(??). ProxyPass works fine, but he is good for one,two instances, not for more.

Comment: Passenger supports multiple gemsets since about forever. Different rubies are only supported in 4.0. If you have many different configs, I'd still rather use something like unicorn, thin, or passenger standalone with a proxy before that. It makes your infrastructure components much less dependent on each other.

Answer (score 0):

I created .htaccess with content below and it working :)

```
RailsBaseURI /
PassengerAppRoot /var/www/redmine
```